# Parse JSONArray in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I am Creating a webapp where i could get the distance and time of travel using google map API..

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=10.964,76.007&destinations=10.982,75.999
```

I am using HTTP method as given by google..
Its returning JSON Format as give below

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Kanyakumari - Panvel Highway, Palathara, Kerala 676501, India" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Kanyakumari - Panvel Highway, Randathani, Kerala 676510, India" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "2.5 km",
                  "value" : 2526
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "4 mins",
                  "value" : 228
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How could i extract the distance text and duration text using jquery and alert it..

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Use `jQuery.parseJSON()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents()` and `json_decode()` the output..

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=10.964,76.007&destinations=10.982,75.999');
$data = json_decode($contents,true);
echo 'Distance : '.$data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
echo "<br>";
echo 'Duration : '.$data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
```

This will give you :

```
Distance : 2.5 km
Duration : 4 mins
```

Comment: welcome bro @KarthikCP glad to help you :) happy coding

Comment: Yeah got it.. The Value is in seconds.. I Just need value to be taken.. anyway thanks

Comment: you can use key 'text' to display distance/time and use 'value' for calculations..